# Partition frequency in Oracle

Tags: oracle, partition

I have enterprise Oracle for the database of our firm.

i also have a table which is partitioned with a frequency of 6 months (2 partitions per year).

Is there any way of Making the partition frequency per month online, without taking the database offline?

Comment: You can simply change the interval to 2 month, but it does not change existing partitions. For this you would need to [split](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin002.htm#i1008028 them.

Comment: but, can this be online without bringing the db offline?

Comment: You don't need to take the database offline to do work on one table, no. And in fact, a partition split can be online so even the table itself can be undergoing application activity, though it's highly recommended that you find a quiet time for that table anyway.

Comment: As per the documentation, The database marks UNUSABLE the new partitions (there are two) in each local index. After Creating the new partitions do i have to rebuild them also?